# Cant debug only in CLion

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, jetbrains-ide

I am not able to hit breakpoints only in `.cpp` files from a specific target in my cmake project using juce.
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is debug, breakpoints can be hit in other INTERFACE targets that this target depends on (juce modules).
The same project is debuggable with Xcode.

Debugging the template repo that my repo is based on works fine, and copying the exact settings from the template does not help as well.
Things that did not help:

- using Xcode generator instead of ninja
- manually setting CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE to debug
- removing .idea files to reset clion project
- fully deleting the full local repository and recloning it

this line at the end if the cmakelists file

```cmake
message("cxx dbg flags: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG}")
message("cxx flags: ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

results in

```
cxx dbg flags: -g
cxx flags:
```

these DBG macros will both be executed

```
#if DEBUG
    DBG("debug enabled");
#endif

#if defined (DEBUG) || defined (_DEBUG) || ! (defined (NDEBUG) || defined (_NDEBUG))
     DBG("any debug enabled");
#endif
```

I am on Ventura 13.2.1

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue - turns out only clion cares about the word case for source paths:

```
#correct path: Source/config.h
set(SourceFiles
    #works
    Source/config.h
    #compiles everywhere; allows debugging on mvs and xcode but not clion
    source/config.h)
```